# Submenu not open in Reduxframework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a theme for WordPress and I am using reduxframework for develope theme panel. when I was implemented admin folder to my theme and set path then I was open WordPress site in the browser and open theme panel but there is submenu not open.

note there is no change in code.

here is my code in this code subsection is not disply on admin side

```
    Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title' => __( 'Basic Fields', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'id'    => 'basic',
    'desc'  => __( 'Basic fields as subsections.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'icon'  => 'el el-home'
) );

Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Heder', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'Custom Logo' ),
    'id'         => 'Header-setting',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'logo',
            'type'     => 'media',
            'url'      =>true,
            'title'    => __( 'Custom Logo', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'desc'     => __( 'Field Description', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'default'  => 'Your Logo',
        ),

    )
) );
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Footer', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'Footer copyright' ),
    'id'         => 'footer-setting',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'copyright-footer',
            'type'     => 'textarea',
            'title'    => __( 'footer copyright', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'desc'     => __( 'footer copyright', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'default'  => 'Site is copyright by company',
        ),
    )
) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that

```
   Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title' => __( 'Basic Fields', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'id'    => 'basic',
    'icon'  => 'el el-home'
) );

Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Heder', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'Custom Logo' ),
    'id'         => 'Header-setting',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'logo',
            'type'     => 'media',
            'url'      =>true,
            'title'    => __( 'Custom Logo', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'desc'     => __( 'Field Description', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'default'  => 'Your Logo',
        ),

    )
) );
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Footer', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'Footer copyright' ),
    'id'         => 'footer-setting',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'copyright-footer',
            'type'     => 'textarea',
            'title'    => __( 'footer copyright', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'desc'     => __( 'footer copyright', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'default'  => 'Site is copyright by company',
        ),
    )
) );
```